# Detecting connection close on AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET socket without using poll

Tags: c, linux, networking, unix-socket

For a bound and connected (to an *unbound* peer) socket created using `socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)`, is there a way to detect that the remote end has hung up, without using `poll` (the `POLLHUP` flag will be set), `select` (for some reason, appearing in the write fd set), or the like?

Unlike `SOCK_STREAM`, 0-length payloads are valid and indistinguishable from the end of the stream (as far as I can tell; I keep getting 0-length chunks when calling `recvmsg` on a socket for which the remote end has called `shutdown` or `close`). Also there aren't any known (to me) flags visible in `struct msghdr` that signal the end of the connection. The only thing I see in the Linux kernel source (`net/unix/af_unix.c:unix_seqpacket_recvmsg`) is the kernel returning `-ENOTCONN` presumably if the socket is not connected, and then performing the same work as for `SOCK_DGRAM`.

Note that it is important to use `recvmsg` rather than `recv`, `recvfrom`, etc, because I need to check the flags for `MSG_TRUNC`.

Comment: Why are `0`-length payloads valid? The man page says `0` return means no more data will be sent from the connected peer.

Comment: That's for `SOCK_STREAM`, despite what the manual says. Documentation about `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is scarce.

Comment: I've got some sample code that does demonstrate a valid 0-length message being sent, or at least the syscall doing that (don't know how to trace what's going on in the kernel). No matter, `recvmsg` hangs until the client does `sendmsg` with the 0-length chunk.

Comment: Why is the client allowed to send a `0`-length chunk? Why doesn't your code just close the connection when that happens?

Comment: I could do that, in *my* case, but was really wondering whether there could be a more general answer, or if the sockets API really can't handle this. I'd have to try to see whether one can pass ancillary data when using `SOCK_SEQPACKET` and with 0-length chunks. If one can, then this would be a specific kludge.

Comment: To me, the issue is really to figure out why and how the client is sending `0`-length chunks. The man page says this means the client has indicated it will send no more data. So, is that what the client did, or not? If not, what did it do instead? If you are trying to distinguish the difference between the client calling `shutdown()` and `close()`, there isn't a way without sending data. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11552492/315052).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35397/discussion-between-pilona-and-jxh)